# Extract characters or Split column (dtype float64)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and I have imported a dataframe with the first column of this df looking as follows (type float64):

```
                        GSR-EDA100C-MRI
2019-05-10 15:59:34.004378    38.967896
2019-05-10 15:59:34.004478    38.964844
2019-05-10 15:59:34.004578    38.966370
2019-05-10 15:59:34.004678    38.964844
...
```

As you can see, this column includes a combination of the date, the time as well as the value I am interested in (38.96...). Is there a way to split up this column into three single columns displaying 'date', 'time', and 'value' and attach it to the existing data frame?

(All suggestions I tried [e.g. df.str.split or df.str.extract] did not work with the float64 datatype since they are based in string characters).

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: `df[["date", "time", "value"]] = df["GSR-EDA100C-MRI"].str.split(expand=True)` ?

Comment: How can a float data type column looks like what you show?

Comment: The first suggestion unfortunately does not work, I get the error "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas" Also, if I run "df.dtypes" I get GSR-EDA100C-MRI          float64.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df = df.split(' ')[-1]
print(df)
```

this should isolate the 38.96

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense that your column is a float! But you could try casting it to string(object) and then split

```
df[["date", "time", "value"]] = df["GSR-EDA100C-MRI"].astype(str).str.split(expand=True)
```